# Design Class with reference to other classes (Objects) OR with values of other classes as much as possible?

Tags: java, class-design

Lets take an example of a simple Blogging application. Given the `BlogPost` class.

```
public class BlogPost {
    private long postId;
    private String postTitle;
    private LocalDateTime postedDate;
    //BlogStatus is an enum
    private BlogStatus postStatus;
   //Getters/Setters
}
```

Which of the following two would make a better design and why ?

```
public class Comment {
    private long commentId;
    private long blogPostId;
    private LocalDateTime commentDateTime;
    private long repliedToCommentId;
    private String commentText;
   //Getters/Setters
}
```

OR

```
public class Comment {
    private long commentId;
    private BlogPost blogPost;
    private LocalDateTime commentDateTime;
    private Comment commentedFor;
    private String commentText;
   //Getters/Setters
}
```

1. Will it make any difference if I were **not to use** any ORM Framework?
2. How to decide when to choose which one ?
3. Here `BlogPost` does not know anything about `Comment`, what if it was to know about it?

May be the example I have taken is **too trivial**, I would be grateful if a better non-trivial example helps.

Thankyou.

Comment: If you are up to some OOP then I think the second approach is better.

Comment: I would like to do OOP, but want to understand if I should it all the time or are there times when I should step back and think no OOP even while using language focused on OOP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the `BlogPost` in a one-to-many relationship with `Comment`. And `Comment` having a reference to a `BlogPost` and list of `Comments` as well (for example, holding the response to the comment). So the second approach of yours is closer to what i think:

```
public class Comment {
    private long commentId;
    private BlogPost blogPost;
    private LocalDateTime commentDateTime;
    private Comment commentedFor;
    private List<Comment> reponses;
    private String commentText;
   //Getters/Setters
}
```